# How can I handle a huge number of requests to a single server?

Tags: ios, load-balancing, sharding, horizontal-scaling

I am working on this personal project of mine which involves an iOS app which retrieves data (an integer value) from the server at my house daily. Right now I have a single server which can handle only about 100-120 concurrent requests per second. However, I want to scale my setup to be able to handle as many as 70-80K requests concurrently while using minimum servers as my budget is limited. Could anyone suggest some techniques for this?

Comment: Does the server have to be at your house?  Google App Engine scales automatically and charges based on usage.  You might investigate that as an option.

Comment: Try Parse (http://parse.com) for a scaling backend, I think their free pack handle more concurrent requests than GAE. Not sure of that, but worth a try.